# Go - After request headers are set, request body is empty

Tags: go, request, go-http

To create an outgoing POST request, [func NewRequest() from net/http](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/go1.19.1:src/net/http/request.go;l=835) library is used.
request body is parsed as a param.
After request is created I set request headers using [Set() func](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/go1.19.1:src/net/http/header.go;l=39). After setting headers, request body is empty.

```
// create a new request 
req, err = http.NewRequest(method, url string, body io.Reader) (*Request, error)
// set headers 
// when I print req.Body at this stage, it's not empty
req.Header.set("foo", "bar")
// when I print req.Body at this stage, it's empty
```

Any of you have met this problem before? and any idea for this?

Comment: How are you printing request body? It is  a stream, if you read it once, you can't read it again.

Answer (score 0):

You would need [`Request.GetBody()`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5Bgolang%5D%20answers%3A0%20closed%3A0) to read/print the Body content without emptying it, as a client requests.

```golang
    // GetBody defines an optional func to return a new copy of
    // Body. It is used for client requests when a redirect requires
    // reading the body more than once. Use of GetBody still
    // requires setting Body.
    //
    // For server requests, it is unused.
    GetBody func() (io.ReadCloser, error)
```

Since:

- `NewRequest` wraps `NewRequestWithContext` using `context.Background`
- `NewRequestWithContext` [set `getBody()`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.19.1:src/net/http/request.go;l=900-914)

You should have that function already defined for your `http.NewRequest` request.

Comment: It works with  Request.GetBody(). Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MyatSuPhyo Great, well done!